# Searching a word in XML file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have almost 2000 files in folder where the count increases daily,and all
the files are in .xml format.The primary requirement is to copy the files from one folder to other ,but checking if files contains "ABC" string.Also the files date should be day-1 till today's date.

I had tried using the below code

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\Raul\Desktop\Test"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\Raul\Desktop\Output"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /m /L "ABC" "%sourcedir%\*.xml"') DO (
 echo(COPY "%%a" "%destdir%\%%~nxa"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Can you help me to modify it?
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's quite well working. Replace `echo(COPY "%%a" "%destdir%\%%~nxa")` to `MOVE "%%a" "%destdir%\%%~nxa"`.

Comment: @sangbok lee-It's not working.the files are not moving to specified folder as required.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide examples of all error messages (add `pause` right before `GOTO :EOF` to keep the `cmd` window open). Consider adding `/Y` switch (Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.)

Comment: I thought you were looking for a tag `<ABC>`

Comment: @Raul Please provide a sample xml file and the exact error message.

Comment: @compo-No ..it's a string in xml file which wont be present in all files.Have to just separate out from the rest.

Comment: @sanbok-As such i am not getting any error since i have created a bat file out of it.The files cannot be seen the destination folder.

Comment: I believe you need to show us examples of the actual string for which you are searching. Possibly add `/c:` directly before the `"ABC"` and remember that the match is case-sensitive (use `/i` to make it case-insensitive. Are you getting the `copy` message shown on-screen? Have you changed the `echo(copy` to `move` ?

Comment: @Magoo-the exact lineis:<payload type="ABC" version="0.1">.Do i need yo add extra " ".i.e.(""ABC"").Yes i had changed it to move.

Answer (score 1):

It's working for a `.xml` file containing `<payload type="ABC" version="0.1">` too. Do replace next line

```
 echo(COPY "%%a" "%destdir%\%%~nxa"
```

to

```
 MOVE "%%a" "%destdir%\%%~nxa"
```

Comment: Lee-Thanks ,it works.But i dont want to move the files.I need a copy of the files to be transferred to the folder.

Comment: Then edit your question so. And replace `MOVE` to `COPY`.